# vala-appmenu does not hide non-global menu for Eclipse

Tags: menu, eclipse, gtk3

vala-appmenu does not hide non-global menu for Eclipse:

[image]
Everything is okay for other GTK2/3 apps (Eclipse is SWT, which is backed by GTK3).

```
DE: xfce 4.12
Distro: Arch Linux
vala-appmenu: 0.7.1.r19.g5bd43fb-1
Eclipse: 4.9.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing `vala-panel-appmenu-registrar-git`.